# Single-SPA localhost CROS origin Issue- React Application

Tags: reactjs, systemjs, single-spa

I'm new to react..I have react application which i migrated to Single-SPA.
To integrate my application with the master application(platform which has many Vue single-spa applications) i have re-structured as

**MainApp** - It includes all the pages related to process - running under localhost:3000

**root-html-file** - it includes one index.html and package.json file
index.html (running under localhost:5000- generate by SPA)

code:
root-html-file -> index.html

```
<script type="systemjs-importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
    "myapp": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "single-spa": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/single-spa/4.3.7/system/single-spa.min.js",
    "react": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.development.js"
     }}</script>

Promise.all([System.import('single-spa'),System.import('react')]).then(function (modules) {
          var singleSpa = modules[0];
            singleSpa.registerApplication(
                'myapp',
                () => System.import('myapp'),
                location => true
            );
          singleSpa.start();
```

myapp application working fine as standalone.
Only when running root-html-file application (npm run serve) which will load myapp application into it causes CROS origin issue.Please find the screenshot

[image]

Please guide me if i'm wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Access Control Allow Origin headers to the React App.
In webpack, it can be done by adding the below to the webpack.config.js file

```
devServer: {
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In case the other answers are not working, or in case if you don't have the webpack config and are using Vite, Craco or anything else instead, then you can try this.

The concept is, let's say you have

> Root project -> running at localhost:5000

> Child Project -> You have built it and then hosted the built files -> which is running at localhost:3000

You will get CORS in the root project if you try to access resources from an endpoint(5000) from any other endpoint(3000).

You can try hosting the child app `build` folder using the below command in the command prompt with `--cors` flag.

```
npx http-party/http-server --port=3000 --cors
```

Here the `--cors` flag will make it suitable to be consumed by localhost:5000 (i.e. your root project).